# Approach for interruptible transition animations

Tags: gui, animation

I found it's very complex to manage transitional animations. For example, when changes to a model get reverted before the animations have completed, the animations for previous changes should stop and the animations for the other direction should start from the middle.

Transitional animation creates a period when the view doesn't not correspond to the model, which breaks the MVC pattern. I wonder whether there is a practical design pattern dealing with this problem.

Comment: generally I find that treating the concept of a transition as it's own component, and breaking that down into MVC standards is a workable solution. What I mean by that is all transitions have generic states [begin, in-action, complete]. these states constitute (conceptually?) 3 models, 3 views and 3 controllers (one for each state). Rolling this up into a transition 'factory' of sorts which manages collections of transitions has been how I've addressed various state awareness/checks.This also helps keep user experience in line because you define common experiences.Is that what you were asking?